# How to consistently retrieve a property from a multi-valued attribute using Kusto

Tags: kql

I have Azure AD audit event sent to a log analytics workspace and I'd like to build a query that shows me all Unified Groups created with the `IsPublic` property set to `True`.

I have the relevant events in `TargetResources[0].modifiedProperties` however this is a multi-valued object and depending on how it was provisioned the position of the attribute I look for is different.

for ex.

`TargetResources[0].modifiedProperties` contains the `IsPublic` on the 3rd position, but sometimes it's on the second or fourth position.

```json
[
    {"displayName":"DisplayName","oldValue":"[]","newValue":"[\"Test Group\"]"},
    {"displayName":"GroupType","oldValue":"[]","newValue":"[\"Unified\"]"},
    {"displayName":"IsPublic","oldValue":"[]","newValue":"[false]"}
]
```

I am guessing there is a way to find the exact property and value dynamically?

Sincerely,
Tonino Bruno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`mv-apply` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mv-applyoperator).

below are a few examples:

```
datatable(i:int, TargetResources:dynamic)
[
    1, dynamic([{"p2":"v2","modifiedProperties":[{"displayName":"DisplayName","oldValue":"[]","newValue":"[\"Test Group\"]"},{"displayName":"GroupType","oldValue":"[]","newValue":"[\"Unified\"]"},{"displayName":"IsPublic","oldValue":"[]","newValue":"[false]"}]}]),
    2, dynamic([{"p4":"v4","modifiedProperties":[{"displayName":"DisplayName","oldValue":"[]","newValue":"[\"Test Group\"]"},{"displayName":"GroupType","oldValue":"[]","newValue":"[\"Unified\"]"},{"displayName":"IsSomething","oldValue":"[]","newValue":"[false]"},{"displayName":"IsPublic","oldValue":"[]","newValue":"[true]"}]}]),
    3, dynamic([{"p2":"v2","modifiedProperties":[{"displayName":"DisplayName","oldValue":"[]","newValue":"[\"Test Group\"]"},{"displayName":"GroupType","oldValue":"[]","newValue":"[\"Unified\"]"},{"displayName":"IsPublic","oldValue":"[]","newValue":"[true]"}]}]),
]
| project i, mp = TargetResources[0].modifiedProperties
| mv-apply mp on ( 
    where mp.displayName == "IsPublic"  and mp.newValue == '[true]'
)
```

```
datatable(i:int, TargetResources:dynamic)
[
    1, dynamic([{"p2":"v2","modifiedProperties":[{"displayName":"DisplayName","oldValue":"[]","newValue":"[\"Test Group\"]"},{"displayName":"GroupType","oldValue":"[]","newValue":"[\"Unified\"]"},{"displayName":"IsPublic","oldValue":"[]","newValue":"[false]"}]}]),
    2, dynamic([{"p4":"v4","modifiedProperties":[{"displayName":"DisplayName","oldValue":"[]","newValue":"[\"Test Group\"]"},{"displayName":"GroupType","oldValue":"[]","newValue":"[\"Unified\"]"},{"displayName":"IsSomething","oldValue":"[]","newValue":"[false]"},{"displayName":"IsPublic","oldValue":"[]","newValue":"[true]"}]}]),
    3, dynamic([{"p2":"v2","modifiedProperties":[{"displayName":"DisplayName","oldValue":"[]","newValue":"[\"Test Group\"]"},{"displayName":"GroupType","oldValue":"[]","newValue":"[\"Unified\"]"},{"displayName":"IsPublic","oldValue":"[]","newValue":"[true]"}]}]),
]
| project i, mp = TargetResources[0].modifiedProperties
| mv-apply mp on ( 
    project displayName = tostring(mp.displayName), newValue = tostring(parse_json(tostring(mp.newValue))[0])
    | summarize b = make_bag(pack(displayName, newValue))
)
| where b.GroupType == "Unified" and b.IsPublic == "true"
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for this suggestion and indeed it works nicely. Just wondering if I have to do a mv-apply for each column I would like to project? Imagine from the sample above I want to have DisplayName and IsPublic projected?

Comment: both examples in the answer use a single `mv-apply` on the array of modified properties, and project a dynamic property bag that includes both `IsPublic` and `DisplayName`. Thus the question in your comment requires further clarification

Comment: apologies I looked into a bit more closely and yes I understand it now. The property bag you create contains everything I need! Much appreciated!